# When predicting using model with log(target) do I have to make any changes to predict function?

Tags: r, regression

I have a dataset where the target variable is skewed left. When I plot a histogram of the log of this variable it's a nice, normal looking distribution. So I believe I should log transform it?

I tried that in my_model below. But when I evaluated it by looking at Mean Absolute Error I found that it under performed against the non log transformed version.

```
my_model <- lm(target ~ ,var1+var2+var3, data=ptrain)
my_model_log <- lm(log(target) ~ ,var1+var2+var3, data=ptrain)

my_predictions <- predict(my_model_log, interval="prediction", newdata=test_submission)
```

my_predictions showed lower performance when using the log model.

Is this expected? Is there a parameter I should add to `predict()` to tell it that the target has bee log transformed before making the prediction?

Comment: ?dput "Writes an ASCII text representation of an R object to a file or connection, or uses one to recreate the object.". You want me to create a file of the data? I'm confused?

Comment: Oh. Maybe a sample since ptrain has over 300k records and 132 vars! Would a small sample of say 100 or 1000 work?

Comment: Is there anything else I can provide that would help? str(ptrain), sample? Visuals of histograms?

Comment: remember that there is no assumption that the outcome in linear regression should be normally distributed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `predict()`, it will return an estimate for log (target). If you want an estimate for target you need to apply the inverse transformation, `exp()`, to the predictions. The prediction interval may have interesting properties.

Comment: That sounds really obvious now that I'm reading it! Thank you. "The prediction interval may have interesting properties.". What does that mean?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi I think this is the answer. Nope, I did not use exp()

Comment: The implicit assumption is that the errors of the transformed values are normally distributed. Can use glm with quasipoisson for different assumptions.

Comment: log( sd(x)) is not equal to sd(log(x)). You can also get a log(x) model with glm( target ~ covariates, family ="quasipoisson"). You can probably find a discussion on the issues and relative merits of these two approaches on CrossValidated.com

Comment: What if the both independent and dependent variables were log transformed? log(y) ~ log(x) would you use the same `exp(predict(model_name))`  syntax to extract the correct predicted values?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a statistics question, not really programming...

There are two independent and potentially conflicting issues:

- does your data look like normal?  (yours looks more like log-normal)
- does your explanatory variables work better as additive, or multiplicative?  (in your case additive may be better)

For instance create additive data with log-normal disturbances:

```
x1 <- runif(1000)
x2 <- runif(1000)
y <- 10*x1 + 10*x2 + rlnorm(1000, mean=0, sd=1)
dat <- data.frame(y, x1, x2)
```

The model is additive (y = x1 + x2) hence you may want to use just
`lm(y~ ...)`.  But it also has non-normal disturbances, so you may
want to run `lm(log(y)~ ...)`

Test the models:

log version

```
m <- lm(log(y)~x1 + x2, data=dat)
mean(abs(dat$y - exp(predict(m) + 0.208^2/2)))
[1] 1.579968
```

non-log version

```
m <- lm(y~x1 + x2, data=dat)
mean(abs(dat$y - predict(m)))
[1] 1.198665
```

Seems like in the non-log model performs better despite the wrong
disturbancs because it gets the
structure correct.

Note I predict the log version as `exp(predict(m) + sigma^2/2)` because $E
exp(X) = exp(mu + sigma^2)$ where $X \sim N(0, sigma^2)$.  (This
changes little here though.)